# How to convert xml gradient to canvas Linear Gradient Programatically?

Tags: android, xml

Want to convert this code in canvas Linear Gradient how to convert angle into x x1 y y1 co ordinations...................

```html
  <gradient
        android:type="linear"
        android:angle="315"
        android:startColor="#D9FF43"
        android:centerColor="#F67831"
        android:endColor="#FF1493"/>
```